# Mispositioned ripple effect on material style

Tags: linux, qt, qml, qt-quick, ripple-effect

I have a QT Quick application on a embedded Linux which use v5.14.2.
I often run the application on Windows because it's easier sometimes with MinGW v5.15.2.

I run Qt Quick 2.6 and Qt Controls 2.5 in the application.

The application is using the material style from qt quick and I have one problem; the ripple effect on controls like a tab bar or a slider is acting differently between the 2 platforms.

To be more specific, I have a simple tab bar in an application Window like this :

```
ApplicationWindow{
    id:root
    width: 800
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page1 {}
        Page2 {}
        Page3 {}
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        Material.accent: "#ff9b22"
        height: 40
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex

        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 1")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 2")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 3")
        }
    }
}
```

On Windows, it's working fine when I click on the footer, the ripple is inside the tab button I clicked on, as it should be.

But on Linux, the ripple goes to the top right of the application and I can't figure out why.

How to get ride of this ripple effect with the material style?

Comment: Do you have a sample QML to run?  Seeing exact controls you are using is probably helpful for someone to answer.  Try to create a minimal QML that shows the effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.